# How to increase Text View's Set Text size method WITHOUT bring the text UP the other objects

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a text view inside a scroll view and two buttons to zoom in and zoom out the text of text size. this is my .xml code:`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:text="@string/test" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/footer">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom In"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom Out"
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and , the code works fine to increase and decrease the size.
But my problem is that :if I zoom in several times, the text get bigger and bigger and then it will shown over the buttons. this is an image of the result:
[image: my result]

I think the problem is in my layout design. please give me your opinion. Tnx

Comment: It's actually under the Buttons, which are partially transparent. What's the root ViewGroup in your layout?

Comment: can you use `layout_above` for this.. the TextView should have based above of Button layout.

Comment: yes, you're all right. @Ranjit Pati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your Relative layout and it would never overlap the buttons.

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Zoom In"
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Zoom Out"
    android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:text="@string/test" />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:text="@string/test" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/footer">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom In"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom Out"
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```